# Partial sum formula for square matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Can the partial sum formula
$$
\frac{1}{xy} = \frac{A}{x}+\frac{B}{y}
$$
be applied for matrices, i.e. the case where $x,y$ are square matrices? If so, what this partial sum formula would be like?

If not, is there a way to resolve a matrix expression involving the sum of two matrices in the denominator somehow as such a partial sum?

Note the question is a bit naive in the sense that matrix division is not defined. Still I would like to know if there is a  nice systematic way to obtain an equation as the one I have written.

Comment: What is division for matrices ?

Comment: We could take the inverses (if the matrices are invertible). So, $\frac{A}{B}:=AB^{-1}$

Comment: @DietrichBurde I have edited. That operation is not defined, but if matrices are invertible you can consider this. But still, I am not sure what Peter means in taking inverse as to produce such an object.

Comment: That's an odd partial sum expression...the left hand is singular if $x=-y$ but the right hand is not.  Usually partial sums separate multiplicative factors, as in $\frac 1{x^2-1}=\frac A{x+1}+\frac B{x-1}$.

Comment: Yes, lulu, completely right.

Answer (score 0):

The equation for matrices could be (If $C$ and $D$ are invertible) :

$$C^{-1}D^{-1}=AC^{-1}+BD^{-1}$$

implying

$$AC^{-1}DC+BC=I$$

But I think completely different approaches are necessary to find a solution and it probably won't be unique.

Comment: Well, could you expand a little bit further? Additionally, in physics we do have objects like $1/ AB$, and I am curious to see if this can be written as some sum.

Comment: matrices are not commutative, this formulations is not correct.  You can write this though $$C'D' = C' A+B D' \implies AD+CB=I $$

Comment: @karakfa Thank you for pointing that out, another reason why we won't get a useful analogy. I think your try to repair the issue does not work because you mutiplied once from the left and once from the right.

Comment: Additionally , you swapped $A$ and $D$.